# How to save your database(mysql) as xlsx(box/spout)

Tags: php, mysql, database, download, xlsx

I'm sorry for my bad english
how to save your database(mysql) as **xlsx(box/spout)** ?
I am using **PHPExcel**, but big files are causing problems
I hear the box/spout is fast.
I'm looking for examples but I could not find a complete narrative

For example, (PHPEXCEL)

```
$Objworksheet-> setcellvalue('A1', 'Hello');
```

sorry again

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://opensource.box.com/spout/

Comment: Yes I have read. But I do not know how to write the data to the cells.
I have a lot of examples for **PHPExcel** but I can not find it for **Spout** 
The problem my english is not good so I am looking for simple examples for spout. I keep on looking to find out. Thank you

Comment: thank you I solved the problem

`$singleRow=['A','B','C'];
$writer->addRow($singleRow);`